# Deploy code from Azure repo to Function app slot

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have setup Azure DevOps repo and pipeline to deploy my code to Azure Functio App slot. I was able to deploy app to my slot but after making some code changes I tried to re deploy my app/code but now pipeline failed. Probably because my pipeline is somehow wrong configured (so it can only deploy if slot is empty but can not update or redeploy on top of existing code).

This is my pipeline

```
- master
variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'My Service Connector'
  # Function app name
  functionAppName: 'My Fuction app name'
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'vs2017-win2016'
  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        if (Test-Path "extensions.csproj") {
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./$(workingDirectory)/bin
        }
      displayName: 'Build extensions'
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: $(workingDirectory)
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true
    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(functionAppName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionApp
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              deployToSlotOrASE: true
              resourceGroupName: 'my app resource group'
              slotName: testing
```

Error from pipeline:

[image]

FYi, I'm not developer nor that familiar with tools like git, repos, pipelines etc. Any tips what could I do different so that I could update my app code from Azure Repos + pipelines?

Comment: The pipeline looks fine to me. In fact, it's almost identical to mine which is working fine. Did anything change to the function app itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change vmImageName: 'vs2017-win2016' to vmImageName: 'windows-lastest' to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up a new ARM connection ([Azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-resource-manager-service-connection)) for use in the pipeline to see if it can work.

If the issue still exists, you can enable debugging via setting the pipeline variable [**`System.Debug`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug) to **`true`**. The queue a new run. From the debug logs, you may get more helpful information about the issue.

Comment: hmm, did not help set up new connection.. Now running system debug not it is not saying that much to me. A lot of 'package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details' and '##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Failed to deploy web package to App Service'